# C# how to get value of a property from a class using generics

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

i am working on asp.net core webapi and using appsettings.json to store some settings. I have a class to get the property value from appsettings using IOptions<>.

Wonder if there is a simple way to use generic to get the property value instead of creating individual method names as i am doing below:

```
public class NotificationOptionsProvider
{
    private readonly IOptions<NotificationOptions> _notificationSettings;
    public NotificationOptionsProvider(IOptions<NotificationOptions> notificationSettings)
    {
        _notificationSettings = notificationSettings;
        InviteNotificationContent = new InviteNotificationContent();
    }

    public string GetRecipientUserRole()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_notificationSettings.Value.RecipientUserRole))
        {
            throw new Exception("RecipientUserRole is not configured");
        }

        return _notificationSettings.Value.RecipientUserRole;
    }

    public string GetInvitationReminderTemplateCode()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_notificationSettings.Value.AssignReminderTemplateCode))
        {
            throw new Exception("InvitationReminderTemplateCode is not configured");
        }

        return _notificationSettings.Value.AssignReminderTemplateCode;
    }

    public string GetSessionBookedTemplateCode()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_notificationSettings.Value.SessionBookedTemplateCode))
        {
            throw new Exception("SessionBookedTemplateCode is not configured");
        }

        return _notificationSettings.Value.SessionBookedTemplateCode;
    }       
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You can't use generics for that, you can use reflection though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just elaborating on canton7's excellent answer; you could preserve the exception text like this:

```
public string GetSetting(Expression<Func<NotificationOptions, string>> selector)
{
    Func<NotificationOptions, string> func = selector.Compile();
    string value = selector(_notificationSettings.Value);
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
    {
        var expression = (MemberExpression)selector.Body;
        throw new Exception($"{expression.Member.Name} is not configured");
    }
    return value;
}
```

Although be aware the call to `.Compile()` will have a performance hit.

Answer (score 3):

You could write something like:

```
public string GetSetting(Func<NotificationOptions, string> selector)
{
    string value = selector(_notificationSettings.Value);
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
    {
        throw new Exception("Not configured");
    }
    return value;
}
```

And call it like:

```
GetSetting(x => x.AssignReminderTemplateCode);
```